# Android App crash on system layout change from seetting

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-appcompat

I am facing issue when change some system setting and open my minimized app from background (taskbar)

Exact case is,

Open my app, then open system setting so my app is minimized
Change font size increase/decrease from setting or enable/disable layout bound from developer option and open my app again then app will crash.

Comment: You should add logcat output here so we can help you!

Comment: @HomayoonAhmadi not getting any thing In logcat, just app restart like crash. even not getting app crash popup.